# Feynman diagram for cubic and quartic interaction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, feynman-diagrams, path-integral

I have a question about the scalar quantum field theory and potential $V(\phi) = \alpha \frac{\phi^3}{3!} + \beta \frac{\phi^4}{4!}$. I want to find some of the possible connected one- and two-loop graphs, which contribute to $<\phi(x_1) \phi(x_2)>$ and to $<\phi(x_1) \phi(x_2) \phi(x_3)>$. I already know what the basic interaction vertices look like, but I don't know how to find the corrections. Any tips are welcome, is there a systematic way to derive the possible graphs?

Comment: possible duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304869/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304869/84967