# Kinetic momentum tensor and causal propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, vector-fields, propagator

I can't find anywhere how the kinetic operator defined as $K_{\mu \nu}$ in the term $A^{\mu}K_{\mu \nu}A^{\nu}$ of the lagrangian density is related to causal propagator (for a vector field). I mean, I know I can obtain causal propagator by calculating kinetic operator, but i cannot find anywhere in my books why, the demonstration and what's the relationship between them. Can someone explain this to me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In the **path integral formalism**, the propagator is *defined* to be the inverse of $K^{\mu\nu}$, so there is nothing to prove. By definition,
$$
K_{\mu\nu}\Delta^{\nu\sigma}_\mathrm{PI}\equiv\delta^\mu_\sigma\tag{1}
$$

In the **operator formalism**, the propagator is defined to be the contraction of two free fields,
$$
\Delta_\mathrm{OF}^{\mu\nu}(x-y)\equiv\overline{A^\mu(x)A}{}^\nu(y)\tag{2}
$$

To calculate $\Delta_\mathrm{OF}^{\mu\nu}$ you have to expand $A^\mu$ in terms of ladder operators, and use the canonical commutators $[a,a^\dagger]\sim 1$. When you do this, you end up with
$$
\Delta^{\mu\nu}_\mathrm{OF}(p)\sim\frac{-\eta^{\mu\nu}}{p^2+i\epsilon}+``p^\mu p^\nu\ \text{terms}"\tag{3}
$$

The function above has the expected property that
$$
K_{\mu\nu}\Delta^{\nu\sigma}_\mathrm{OF}=\delta^\mu_\sigma\tag{4}
$$
as can be checked by direct computation (left to the reader).

In the operator formalism, the equation $K_{\mu\nu}\Delta^{\nu\sigma}_\mathrm{OF}=\delta^\mu_\sigma$ is a corollary, so to speak. You  can only conclude that this relation holds **a posteriori**, once you've explicitly calculated the propagator.

After all this, we end up with
$$
\Delta_\mathrm{OF}^{\mu\nu}=\Delta_\mathrm{PI}^{\mu\nu}\tag{5}
$$

The important point is that in the operator formalism, **there is no general proof** that
$$
K_{\mu\nu}\Delta^{\nu\sigma}_\mathrm{OF}\equiv\delta^\mu_\sigma\tag{6}
$$
but, rather, you have to **check this case by case**. It can be proven that this relation always holds as long as [Wick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wick's_theorem#Wick.27s_theorem_applied_to_fields) is satisfied, but this isn't necessarily true for any theory. For more details, see [Are the path integral formalism and the operator formalism inequivalent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252213).