# A derivation of the canonical commutation relations (CCR) written by Dirac?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, lie-algebra, poisson-brackets

Dirac in his book fundamental of quantum mechanic used the following derivation:

[image]

Is this a derivation of the canonical commutation relations (CCR) in quantum mechanics?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a derivation per se, more like a suggestive argument. Dirac is assuming that the usual [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) on the algebra of *functions* can be replaced by a bracket $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ on the algebra of *operators* that satisfies a non-commutative Leibniz rule
$$\{\hat{a}\hat{b},\hat{c}\}~=~\hat{a}\{\hat{b},\hat{c}\}+\{\hat{a},\hat{c}\}\hat{b}.$$
In other words, $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ is a non-commutative Poisson structure, just like the commutator $[\cdot,\cdot]$. It is perhaps not too surprising that consistency then suggests that  $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ and $[\cdot,\cdot]$ are proportional.