# How do we know that correlation functions in canonical quantization equal those obtained with path integration?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, path-integral, correlation-functions

In quantum field theoy, let's say the free scalar field theory, we can compute the $n$-point correlation function $\langle 0|T(\phi(x_1),...,\phi(x_n))|0\rangle$ using Wick's theorem.

Alternatively, we can differentiate the generating the generating function $$W_0[J]=\exp\bigg[-\frac{1}{2}\frac{i}{\hbar}\int d^4x'\,d^4x\,\,J(x')\Delta_F(x'-x)J(x)\bigg]$$ which gives $$\langle 0|T(\phi(x_1),...,\phi(x_n))|0\rangle=\bigg(\frac{\hbar}{i}\bigg)^n\frac{\delta^nW[J]}{\delta J(x_1)...\delta J(x_n)}\bigg|_{J=0}.$$

My question is: the path integral derivation of $W_0[J]$ I found in standard textbooks requires some extraordinary leap of faith (with fermions the leap only gets bigger), so it is not immediately obvious to me why the two approaches must yield identical answers.

Of course we can check the special case of a free scalar field theory, as it's just a combinatorial problem. However, it's there a better explanation why this should hold? Not just free scalar field, but free fermions, Yukawa theory, QED etc?

Comment: What "leaps of faith" are you referring to?

Comment: My understanding is that in QFT path integrals are defined by discretizing the spacetime then compute that way. However in textbooks we just treat $\mathcal{D}\phi$ as a single variable and treat integrals like $\int\mathcal{D}\phi e^{-\phi^2}=\sqrt{\pi}$. I don't see the justification for this. For fermions tthere's even less justification.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Are the path integral formalism and the operator formalism inequivalent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252213/2451) and links therein.