# Does the order of variables matter for a quantum Lagrangian in the path integral formula for quantum mechanics?

Tags: mathematical-physics, lagrangian-formalism, operators, path-integral

For a single particle or field, I can't see how the [path-integral formulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) depends on the order of terms in the Lagrangian. It seems that you integrate the classical Lagrangian to get the action on a path, then integrate over all paths.

Since we use the classical Lagrangian (I presume?), does this mean that the order of terms does not matter?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56070/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks! Completely answered my question.