# Inconsistency of numbers of $d p$ and $d q$ in path integrals over phase space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, boundary-conditions, phase-space

I am new to QFT. In books like Fradkin's *QFT an integrated approach*, and Stefan's *Gauge field theories 2nd Ed.*, they derive the path integral from first writing down the integral over the phase space,
$$
\lim_{N\to +\infty} \int \left\{\prod_{n=1}^{N-1} \mathrm{d}q_n\right\} \left\{\prod_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\mathrm{d}p_n}{2\pi\hslash}\right\} 
\exp\left[{\frac{i}{\hslash} \varepsilon \sum_{n=1}^N p_n \frac{q_n - q_{n-1}}{\varepsilon} - H(\overline{q}_n, p_n)}\right]
$$
And then proceed with
$$
\int \frac{\mathcal D q \mathcal D p}{2\pi \hbar} 
\exp\left[{\frac{i}{\hslash} \varepsilon \sum_{n=1}^N p_n \frac{q_n - q_{n-1}}{\varepsilon} - H(\overline{q}_n, p_n)}\right]
$$
with the notation of $ \mathcal D q \mathcal D p $ meaning the equal number of product of $dq$ and $dp$ going to infinity,
$$\mathcal D q \mathcal D p = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} dp_i dq_i/2\pi \hbar \tag{1}$$

**I am wondering if that missing $dq$ matters.** Dimension-wise, at least the Stefan book made amendments to the dimension, while the Fradkin book didn't. I am not sure if that's how we write the functional integral.

**Edit**:
I mean I do agree that there should be one less $dq$. And I see how that comes about. But why are we ignoring this missing $dq$ (or discarding the extra $dp$) when we go to the equation 1?

Comment: If your amplitude takes you from 0 to $q_N$, you might not want to sum over all end points?

Comment: @CosmasZachos yes I know we SHOULD have one less. I guess my question is: is it correct to assume an equal number of $dp$ and $dq$ when we go to $N\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Why not? isn't this what infinity means?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/134714/226902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because there are 1 less position integration due to

1. the Dirichlet boundary conditions
   $$q(t_0)~=~q_0\quad\text{and}\quad q(t_N)~=~q_N,$$
2. and the fact that the insertion of complete sets of position resp. momentum eigenstates in phase space path integral alternates temporally
   $$ p(t_{1/2}),\quad q(t_1),\quad p(t_{3/2}),\quad q(t_2),\quad \ldots,\quad p(t_{N-3/2}), \quad q(t_{N-1}),\quad p(t_{N-1/2}),$$
   along the time discretization,
   $$t_n~=~t_0+n\epsilon, \quad \epsilon ~=~ \frac{t_N-t_0}{N}, \quad N~\in~\mathbb{N},\quad n~\in~\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}. $$

Comment: So there is INDEED one less $dq$, and the books saying that when we take $N$ to infinity we still want to keep that difference in number of $dp$ and $dq$?

Comment: The difference of 1 is independent of $N$, if that's what you're asking.