# Does this Fermion path integral have a solution?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, boundary-conditions, grassmann-numbers

This is a question on the mathematics of path integration.

If we take the action density $S[\phi](t) = \frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}\dot{\phi}$ and we take the path integral

$$K_T(A,B) = \left. \int e^{-\int_0^T S[\phi](t)} D\phi\right|_{\phi(0)=A}^{\phi(T)=B} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi T}} e^{-(A-B)^2/(2T)}\tag{1}$$

Where the path integral is over all fields $\phi(t)$ with $0<t<T$ with boundary conditions set. (I don't if there is a common way of writing boundary conditions for function integrals). One can prove this by breaking the functional integral into an infinite set of integrals over each of $\phi(t)$. It satisfies:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty K_{t_1}(A,B)K_{t_2}(B,C) dB= K_{t_1+t_2}(A,C).\tag{2}$$

So I wanted to do the same for the simplest Fermion type action $$S[\psi](t)=\dot{\psi}\psi - \psi\dot{\psi}.\tag{3}$$ i.e. where $\psi$ is Grassmann-valued and hence $$\psi(t_1)\psi(t_2) = -\psi(t_2)\psi(t_1)\tag{4}$$ for any $t_1$ and $t_2$

$$K_T(a,b) = \left. \int e^{-\int_0^T S[\psi](t)} D\psi\right|_{\psi(0)=a}^{\psi(T)=b} = \text{undefined?}\tag{5}$$

Is there a way to make sense of such an integral or is it ill defined?  It seems to have *two different solutions* depending on if we divide the time interval into an even or an odd number of small pieces!

Answer (score 2):

If we consider the coherent state path integrals, they still enjoy the semigroup property (2), and we don't have to worry about functional determinants.

1. The bosonic coherent state path integral is
   $$\begin{align} \langle z_f^{\ast}, t_f | z_i, t_i \rangle ~=~& 
   \int_{z(t_i)=z_i}^{\bar{z}(t_f)=z^{\ast}_f} \! {\cal D}\bar{z}~{\cal D}z ~e^{iS[z,\bar{z}]}, \cr  
   {\cal D}\bar{z}~{\cal D}z~:=~& \prod_{n=1}^N \frac{d\bar{z}_n~dz_n}{2 \pi i}, \end{align}\tag{A}$$
   $$\begin{align}   iS[z,z^{\ast}]~:=&~ (1-\lambda)z^{\ast}(t_f)~z(t_f) + \lambda  z^{\ast}(t_i) z(t_i) \cr +& \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! dt  \left[\lambda \dot{z}^{\ast} z -(1-\lambda) z^{\ast} \dot{z}- iH_N(z^{\ast},z)  \right],\end{align}\tag{B}$$
   $$\begin{align}  | z, t \rangle~:=~& e^{\hat{a}^{\dagger}(t)z}| 0 \rangle,\cr
   \int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{d\bar{z}~dz}{2 \pi i} e^{-\bar{z}z} |z \rangle\langle \bar{z} |~=~&\mathbb{1}.
   \end{align}\tag{C}$$
   where $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ is a real constant which the action (B) does not actually depend on, due to the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). For more details, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210138/2451) related Phys.SE post.
2. The fermionic coherent state path integral is similarly
   $$\begin{align} \langle \eta_f^{\ast}, t_f | \eta_i, t_i \rangle ~=~& 
   \int_{\eta(t_i)=\eta_i}^{\bar{\eta}(t_f)=\eta^{\ast}_f} \! {\cal D}\bar{\eta}~{\cal D}\eta ~e^{iS[\eta,\bar{\eta}]}, \cr  
   {\cal D}\bar{\eta}~{\cal D}\eta~:=~& \prod_{n=1}^N d\bar{\eta}_n~d\eta_n, \end{align}\tag{D}$$
   $$\begin{align}   iS[\eta,\eta^{\ast}]~:=&~ (1-\lambda)\eta^{\ast}(t_f)~\eta(t_f) + \lambda  \eta^{\ast}(t_i) \eta(t_i) \cr +& \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\! dt  \left[\lambda \dot{\eta}^{\ast} \eta -(1-\lambda) \eta^{\ast} \dot{\eta}- iH_N(\eta^{\ast},\eta)  \right],\end{align}\tag{E}$$
   $$\begin{align}  | \eta, t \rangle~:=~& e^{\hat{c}^{\dagger}(t)\eta}| 0 \rangle,\cr
   \int_{\mathbb{C}^{0|1}} d\bar{\eta}~d\eta ~e^{-\bar{\eta}\eta} |\eta \rangle\langle \bar{\eta} |~=~&\mathbb{1}.
   \end{align}\tag{F}$$

The complex Grassmann-odd variable $\eta\in \mathbb{C}^{0|1}$ can be decomposed into two real Grassmann-odd variables $\in \mathbb{R}^{0|1}$. There is a similar construction for a single real Grassmann-odd variable, which is OP's question.

References:

1. A. Altland & B. Simons, *Condensed matter field theory,* 2nd ed., 2010; p. 160-164.
2. T. Lancaster & S.J. Blundell, *QFT for the Gifted Amateur,* 2014; section 28.2.

Comment: No doubt this is correct. But I'm not sure how to use this to work out the integral in the question in which I wrote "undefined" which is related to the specific action stated?

Comment: Notes to self: Given a Hermitian fermionic mode $\hat{c}^2=\hbar\hat{\bf 1}$, how does the corresponding coherent states work out? $\hat{c}|0\rangle=|1\rangle$ and $\hat{c}|1\rangle=|0\rangle$.

Comment: Notes to self: Def. (F) agrees with Altland & Simons (4.17).