# What is the meaning of the function of $x$ and $p$ that you get when you cut open the phase space path integral?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, path-integral, boundary-conditions, phase-space

When we "cut" an ordinary path integral, we obtain a state in the position representation. That is, if we fix some initial position $x_i$, then the path integral
$$\int_{x_i}^{x_f}Dx e^{-S}$$
is just a complex function of the final position $x_f$ - i.e. it's just a wavefunction $\psi(x_f)$.

The phase space path integral is given by
$$\int DxDp e^{i\int(p\dot{q}-H)dt}.$$ Usually, this path integral is thought of as a function of the initial and final positions, which are fixed, whilst the initial and final momenta are not fixed: all values of $p_i$ and $p_f$ are integrated over. But one could instead choose to think of it as a function of both the final position and final momentum, giving us some function $f(x_f,p_f)$.

Clearly $f$ isn't a wavefunction, since it depends on too many variables. I'd like to know: is  $f$ equal to some well-known function of $x$ and $p$ (e.g. the Wigner distribution)? And does it carry any physical meaning?

Note that a totally valid answer might be "no, $f$ doesn't appear in the literature, and as far as we know it has no physical meaning".

Comment: It can't literally be the Wigner distribution because this path integral isn't, in general, real-valued. (But I expect some similar thing is true because the Wigner distribution behaves like a probability distribution so there must be a way to build it up from time slices giving a path integral of some sort.)

Comment: It's a long story, and it's been beaten to a pulp. You might  like to read the paragraph around eqn (120) of [this booklet](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf), which provides the propagator for Wigner functions, and references in that paragraph...

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Hamiltonian phase space [path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) on a [symplectic manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) the initial and final boundary conditions are typically given by a choice of 2 [Lagrangian submanifolds](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lagrangian+submanifold).
2. This rules out OP's example where OP specifies both $x_f$ and $p_f$ but has no initial conditions.
3. Note however that the coherent state path integral is an important exception with overcomplete boundary conditions, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/210138/2451) related Phys.SE post.
4. Often the path integral as a function of the final condition can be interpreted as a wavefunction that satisfies the Schrödinger equation, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65489/2451) related Phys.SE post for the standard case.