# Can this shape of matrix elements in the path integral formalism be linked to some sort of expectation value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, path-integral, probability, observables

This question is about expressions of the form
$$
\langle x_f, t_i | \hat{x}(t) | x_i, t_i \rangle = \frac{1}{N} \int_{x(t_i) = x_i}^{x(t_f) = x_f} \mathcal{D} x~x(t)e^{i S[x]}.
$$

In the following the states and operators are meant to be understood in the Heisenberg picture.
I know how to arrive at the rhs of the equation: Putting an identity into the lhs:
$$
\langle x_f, t_i | \hat{x}(t) \int dx |x, t \rangle \langle x,t | | x_i, t_i \rangle  \\
= 
 \int dx  \langle x_f, t_i |x, t \rangle x \langle x, t | x_i, t_i \rangle \\
= \int dx K(x_f, t_f, x, t)  x K(x, t, x_i, t_i) \\
= \int dx \frac{1}{N_f} \int_{x(t) = x}^{x(t_f) = x_f} \mathcal{D} x e^{i S[x]}  x \frac{1}{N_i} \int_{x(t_i) = x_i}^{x(t) = x} \mathcal{D} x ~ x(t)e^{i S[x]} \\
= \frac{1}{N} \int_{x(t_i) = x_i}^{x(t_f) = x_f} \mathcal{D} x  x(t)e^{i S[x]}.
$$

**What is the meaning of this object? Can this be thought of an "expectation value" of some sort?**

Of course, the argument is somewhat clear (as also mentioned in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/679014/):For a given $x$, $x_i$ and $x_f$ you get (by $K(x_f, t_f, x, t)$ the probability-AMPLITUDE that a particle that was at $x_i$ at time $t_i$ will be at $x$ at time $t$, and with $K(x, t, x_i, t_i)$ the probability-amplitude that a particle starting at $x$ at time $t$ will be found at $x_f$ at time $t_f$.

So if you definitely know that the particle started at $x_f$ and ended at $t_f$ then the product of both yields the Amplitude by which the particle was at $x$ at time t. Integrating over all x might then give you what is widely called "expectation value" - except for some difficulties (that the cited question sadly doesn't resolve):

- For the expectation value interpretation to hold, wouldn't we need the probability (absolute square of $K * K$? )
- Can we be sure that the result is real? I tried to take the complex conjugate, but in order to proof that it will be the same result, I need to make additional assumptions on $K$
- Usually expectation values are taken between the same states, but even between same states, we still have problems with expression not neccessarily being real.

Comment: I would say an expectation value for some Hermitian operator $O$ would be $\langle \Psi | O | \Psi\rangle$ -- in other words, the state in the bra and ket are the same. If the bra and ket are different, like $\langle \Phi | O | \Psi \rangle$, I would call that a matrix element. Different people use different conventions , but off hand I don't recall  hearing an expression like $\langle \Phi | O | \Psi \rangle$ referred to as an expectation value. It certainly is not real and can't be interpreted as an average value of $O$, so if you have seen this I think it is just sloppy language.

Comment: Called an expectation value by whom? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic it seems I missread the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation#Expectation_values_and_matrix_elements

More general, those objects seem to be called "matrix Elements", because of that I will try to reshape my question.